# Maven - how to download dependency from explicitly set url

Tags: maven, papervision3d

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.papervision3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>Papervision3D</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.932</version>
        <type>swc</type>
        <downloadUrl>http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/files/Papervision3D_2.1.932.swc</downloadUrl>
    </dependency>
```

I'm supposed to use `downloadUrl` tag, but this throws 'Badly formed Maven project'. Where I'm supposed to set the downloadUrl values for this (or any other) dependency.

Also pointing a repository containing Papervision3d, will be also considered as answer of this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a dependency to something that's available from your system:

```
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>.../Papervision3D_2.1.932.swc</systemPath>
```

That won't work with URL's, I think.

The best solution is to manually install it in your local repository, or deploy it in your team's repository if you have one.

See [install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).